# Fluent NHibernate mapping to view and table

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a situation where I would like to write data to both an Entity table and an Entity view.

We are migrating the *source of truth* for some data in a table from a single multi-tenant database to many database-per-tenant databases.  Due to the large number of clients to be migrated, this will be performed in a number of phases.

The view has been written to return data from a synonym if the data has been migrated, or from the original table if it has not.

```
create view dbo.vwEntity
as 
select 
     e.id
    ,case
        when s.IsMigrated = 1 then e_syn.Field1
        else e.Field1
     end                    as 'Field1' /* Migrated Field */
    ,e.Field2                           /* Non-Migrated Field */
from dbo.tblEntities as e
    left outer join dbo.synEntity as e_syn
        on e_syn.Id = e.Id
    inner join dbo.tblSystem as s
        on s.SystemId = e.SystemId;
```

We have a very large legacy application that was the original *source of truth* for all data in this table.
For those clients that have been migrated, migrated data used by this legacy application is read only (so the `ClassMap<>` entity fields are decorated with `.Not.Update()`) but for those clients that have not been migrated, all data must be updatable.
By updating the Mapping class to use the new view, we no longer have the ability to update data for those clients that have not been migrated.

There is an article on `NHibenate.info` from 2009 describing how to do this using *NHibernate* XML files and the `EntityName` attribute (https://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/mapping/mapping-the-same-class-to-a-view-and-a-table-using-entity-name). I've attempted to replicate this using *Fluent NHibernate* yet when adding an `EntityName` call in the mapping class constructor, I get a `Duplicate class/entity mapping` exception when calling the `BuildConfiguration()`function on the `FluentConfiguration` object.

I am using the NuGet packages

- NHibernate : 4.0.4.4000
- Fluent NHibernate : 2.0.3

I cannot upgrade to NHibernate 5.0.0 as this requires a .Net framework upgrade that we are unable to perform right now.  Which also rules out upgrading Fluent NHibernate to 2.1.0 as this requires `NHibernate 5.0.3`.

I was thinking of using `SubclassMap<>` classes and updating the view to only return the migrated data, but since the original table will still exist, multiple rows of data for those clients that have been migrated will be returned.

Does anyone have an idea how to help?

View Mapping Class

```
public class EntityMapView : ClassMap<Entity>
{
    public EntityMap()
    {
        Table("vwEntity");
        Id(t => t.Id);
        Map(t => t.Field1).Not.Update();
        Map(t => t.Field2);
    }
}
```

Entity Mapping Class

```
public class EntityMapTable : ClassMap<Entity>
{
    public EntityMap()
    {
        Table("tblEntity");
        Id(t => t.Id);
        Map(t => t.Field1);
        Map(t => t.Field2);
    }
}
```

**Update for @Firo** : 2022-10-04 11:33 UDT

Entity Mapping Class with `EntityName`

```
public class EntityMapTable : ClassMap<Entity>
{
    public EntityMap()
    {
        Table("tblEntity");
        EntityName("EntityTable");
        Id(t => t.Id);
        Map(t => t.Field1);
        Map(t => t.Field2);
    }
}
```

A little detail on the exception also may help.

```
[DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping EntityTable]
   NHibernate.Cfg.Mappings.AddClass(PersistentClass persistentClass) +201
   NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.RootClassBinder.Bind(HbmClass classSchema, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas) +1127
   NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.MappingRootBinder.AddEntitiesMappings(HbmMapping mappingSchema, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas) +125
   NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.MappingRootBinder.Bind(HbmMapping mappingSchema) +113
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDeserializedMapping(HbmMapping mappingDocument, String documentFileName) +184

[MappingException: Could not compile the mapping document: (XmlDocument)]
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.LogAndThrow(Exception exception) +117
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDeserializedMapping(HbmMapping mappingDocument, String documentFileName) +444
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.ProcessMappingsQueue() +26
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddInputStream(Stream xmlInputStream, String name) +172
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDocument(XmlDocument doc, String name) +344
   FluentNHibernate.PersistenceModel.Configure(Configuration cfg) +842
   FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildConfiguration() +184

[FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.

]
```

Comment: Can you post the mapping with the `... when adding an EntityName ...` ?

Comment: @Firo, I've updated the issue description.  Basically, simply adding the `EntityName("<SomeValue>");`  to the constructor causes the error.

Comment: It works in a test project for me. Try specifying the entity name on both explicitly and make sure to only add it once.